# How to Insert Array data into database in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-contacts

I am creating a react native app to load phone book contacts to my app [using this library.](https://github.com/logisticinfotech/react-native-contact-multi-select) I loaded contact correctly in my app. Now I wanted to save contact details into the SQL database. How can I insert array data into the SQL database?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save data into your device storage, first you have to decide what storage or library you want to use. There are 2 common types of storage  that you can look into:

- [Async storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage): asynchronous, unencrypted, persistent, key-value storage
- SQL or other storage engines: you can choose what library fits your needs (SQLite, realm, .etc). You can find them [here](https://www.awesome-react-native.com/#Components-Storage). I highly recommend [WatermelonDB](https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB) which is good for scaling and can connect to your react components to re-render when there are changes in the database.

If you only need to store a small number of simple records. Async storage can work just fine. In case you need a relational database or a larger number of records, you can use the latter options.

Comment: Actually I am using an API to process my data. I created an API with .NET CORE. And I used the SQL server management studio as my database. Now I want to store contact details in my database.  I used a library to load contacts into my app and it contain an array with contact detail. I want to insert that array data into my database.

Comment: @Sidath in that case, you can make a request to your API and store your data. This document describes how to make a request to an API https://reactnative.dev/docs/network. You should use POST method and post your array of contact details in the body of the request (you can see the example in the document).

Comment: Ok, I'll try with these steps. And I have no idea about my database structure. In order to this library (https://github.com/logisticinfotech/react-native-contact-multi-select) that array contains a full-name, number, and avatar. I need to store the name and contact number only. How should I make my database structure? Please Give me an idea.

Comment: @Sidath you should separate the front-end and the back-end, and communicate using RESTful API (json). So in the front-end you can use any library that you like, and in the back-end you can parse the json to your .NET object and store it using SQL. You can look into Relational Database Design to find a good way to design your database.